# How to filter remove None types from List[(String , Option[Int])]?

Tags: scala

Here I'm attempting to remove `None` type from a list of `(String , Option[Int])` where the `None` type can be at position 2 in the tuple :

```
val l : List[(String , Option[Int])] = List(
         ("a" , None),
         ("b" , Option(1)),
         ("c" , Option(2))
    )

val filteredSomes = for { 
    (e <- l)
        if(e._2 >= 0)
} yield e

println(filteredSomes);
```

But this does not compile :

causes error :

```
 ')' expected but '<-' found.
[error]                 (e <- l)
[error]                    ^
```

Can `flatten` be used against this collection instead of for each ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Similar to the cheseaux's answer, but more idiomatic:

```
l.filter(_._2.isDefined)
```

Comment: Where is the nonnegative constraint? If I correctly understand what the OP wants, the expression should be `l.filter(_._2.exists(_ >= 0))`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that part. You can fold the Option as well:

1.filter(_._2.fold(false)(_ >= 0))

Which basicall means, if _._2 is None, then return false, else return the result >= 0

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply

```
l.filter(_._2 != None)
```

Or if you really want to express it using the `for comprehensions` form, you can do it like this

```
for(e <- l; if (e._2 != None)) yield e
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish the same thing by using a filter with some pattern matching:

```
val filteredSomes = l.filter {

    // This is the only case that you want to pass your filter.
    // We are pattern matching the tuple and saying that we don't 
    // care about the String's value but we want the Option[Int] 
    // to be defined and be greater-than-or-equal to zero
    case (_, Some(i)) if i >= 0 => true 

    // Any other case should not pass the filter
    case _ => false 
}
```

Here is an example from the Scala REPL

```
scala> val l : List[(String , Option[Int])] = List(("a" , None), ("b" , Option(1)), ("c" , Option(2)))
l: List[(String, Option[Int])] = List((a,None), (b,Some(1)), (c,Some(2)))

scala> l.filter { 
     |     case (_, Some(i)) if i >= 0 => true
     |     case _ => false
     | }
res6: List[(String, Option[Int])] = List((b,Some(1)), (c,Some(2)))
```

Comment: Pattern matching on `Option` is usually a code smell, though. There are so many useful `Option` combinators that pattern matching is hardly ever required. See, for instance, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ol2AB5UN1IA

Comment: More succinctly: `for (a @ (_, Some(b)) <- l if b > 0) yield a`

Comment: @Jubobs I would say this is one instance where pattern-matching on an `Option` may be preferred as it makes it a little more clear where `i` is coming from. On the other hand, when mapping to a literal `true` or `false`, there is usually a better way.

Comment: @MichaelZajac I personally prefer `l filter { _._2 exists { _ >= 0 } }`.

Comment: @Jubobs I didn't know pattern matching on Options was bad practice, thanks for the video!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `collect`

```
List(
  ("a" , None),
  ("b" , Option(1)),
  ("c" , Option(2)),
  ("d",  Option(-1))
) collect {case t @ (_, Some(i)) if i >= 0 => t}
//result: List((b,Some(1)), (c,Some(2)))
```

Comment: You can also upack the tuple `case (s, Some(i)) => s -> i` if you want to get rid of the option monad